# JFreeChart loading an array into dataset

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, jfreechart

I have trouble loading an array via a simple for loop into JFreeChart's DataSet. For example this will world perfectly fine:

```
    private  PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();     

    result.setValue("Linux", 29);
    result.setValue("Mac", 20);
    result.setValue("Windows", 51);

    return result;

}
```

However if I try to implement the code above with arrays by looping through each element of the array it will not work:

```
    private  PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    int[] array1 = new int[]{29,20,51};
    char[] array2 = new char[]{"Linux", "Mac", "Windows"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        result.setValue(array2[i], array1[i]);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [signature for `DefaultPieDataset.setValue()` is](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/DefaultPieDataset.html)

```
setValue(java.lang.Comparable key, double value)
```

So I don't think an array of chars allows for "`Comparable`" values in said array.
An array of `String` might (`String` implementing the `Comparable` interface, which is why your first example is working).